# My question was migrated to AskDifferent.com?  Is that normal?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, migration

I just posted a question about SSH and my iPhone:

[Is it possible to access an iPhone over SSH on 3G?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50271/is-ssh-possible-on-remote-networks#comment479755_419580)

And I see my question is on another site called Ask Different.  I don't see Ask Different on the Stack Exchange network (at the footer), nor is the Stack Exchange bar active on that site.

Is that a hack attempt or something normal?

Comment: AskDifferent is in the footer, but it's called "apple" there. I'm not sure why you're not seeing a Stack Exchange icon, though... you should be. It is a legit SE site, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes - it was a question about hardware or software that was better suited (or would have got a better answer) at Ask Different - seen under "Apple" in the site footer. Ask Different is the StackExchange site for Apple-related questions.

Don't worry, questions often get migrated between sites to a place where they are a better fit. No hacking going on here - just four SuperUser users and a SuperUser mod decided it would be better on AskDifferent.

Oh, and the StackExchange bar is there, it's just a different colour scheme than the normal "trilogy" sites (SuperUser, StackOverflow, ServerFault).

Answer (score 9):

There is a handful of SE sites whose status as SE site isn't immmediately obvious. Examples include:

- [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)
- [Super User](http://superuser.com)
- [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com)
- [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)
- [Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com)
- [Answers OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com)

Most users are familiar with the first two, since they form part of the `S[OFU]` trilogy.

In addition, there are a couple of simple redirects in place that might contribute to confusion:

- [nothingtoinstall.com](http://nothingtoinstall.com) redirects to [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)
- [seasonedadvice.com](http://seasonedadvice.com) redirects to [Cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com)

[AskDifferent](http://askdifferent.com) is actually just [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com), and it appears with the latter name in most places.

Your question was migrated for a reason: It's not a question about computer hardware or software, so it's off topic on Super User. In fact, the Super User FAQ explicitly states:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> ...
>
> and it is not about …
>
> ...
>
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer

The only other option would have been to close your question without migration.

Check out the [Ask Different FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq), and you'll see that it fits perfectly there.

Comment: The OP's question was actually asked on SuperUser, not StackOverflow, so this question would have been better suited to meta.superuser.

Comment: I see. The title says `My question on stackoverflow...`, so you'll understand my confusion.

Comment: yup. If you look at the migrated question it said "Migrated from SuperUser.com" - the OP got this wrong. And I just edited the title.

Answer (score 6):

Migrations are possible only to sites that are part of Stack Exchange; if you see a question migrated on a site you don't know, that is surely part of Stack Exchange.
Not even moderators can migrate a question to a site that is not part of Stack Exchange. What moderators see when closing a question is something similar to the following screenshot, which has been taken from *Drupal Answers*, where I am a moderator.

[image: screenshot]

The question you are referring has been migrated from *Super User*, not *Stack Overflow*.

[image: screenshot]

There is an overlap between *Super User* and *Ask Different*, but questions about Apple devices, such as iPhone, iPad, iPod are off-topic on *Super User*, and on-topic on *Ask Different*.

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - **electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer**
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> … then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: +1 for the screenshot of the Super Secret Mod Interface :)

Answer (score 2):

AskDifferent is part of the StackExchange network (check the url) and there is a StackExchange bar. This is normal.